# while($query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5)).How many times it will run?If it select 4 values from the database

Tags: php

I am applying while loop in php but it is running 4 times because it selects 4 values from the database.but i want to run while loop according to if else condition define by me.

```
<td style="border:1px solid;padding:11px;">
<?php   
    $query5=mysql_query("select atime from doctorbooking where aday='2016-09-29' and demail='".$query2['email']."'");

    while( $query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5)) {           
        if (($array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1])==$query6['atime']) {
            echo $array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1] . '<br /><span style="color:red;background-color:#C0C0C0;">Booked</span>';

        } else {
            echo $array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1] . '<br /><span style="color:red;">Available</span>';
        }           
    }    
?>
</td>
```

Comment: from where this `$array_of_time` comes? and what is `$key` ? how it's values come from? these are undefined in your question

Comment: @Anant Yes, but they are irrelevant for the OPs question.

Comment: $array_of_time is showing time.@Anant.

Comment: I'd say if the query does as you claim return 4 entries, then the `mysql_fetch_array()` function will be executed 5 times. Once for each entry, once returning a `false` and terminating the loop. The _loop_ will only be executed 4 times, though.

Comment: A side note: you should add error detection and handling instead of blindly trusting that everything works...

Comment: Yes it is running 4 times because it selects 4 values from the database.but i want to run one time according to the if else condition .Please help.@arkascha.

Comment: Can i send you my code.@arkascha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123756/discussion-between-rahul-pamnani-and-arkascha).

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: You just have to test each 4 (or N) results matching your timeinterval if-else before echoing anything, then do a second loop with the echoing part. You cannot know in advance if the database result will match if you dont grab them in a way or another.

Comment: Yes you are right.but Can you explain with code@Proger_Cbsk.Please

Comment: I posted a suggestion in the chat window, as promised. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123756/discussion-between-rahul-pamnani-and-arkascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic, your array_of_time can only be *available* or *booked* . So you need to turn on a flag and check it afterward.
I dont know if you want to show *available* in priority or *booked* so the example below will force *booked* :

```
<td style="border:1px solid;padding:11px;">
<?php

  $array_filter = $array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1];
  $is_booked = false; //set it true if you want to force "available"

  $query5=mysql_query("select atime from doctorbooking where aday='2016-09-29' and demail='".$query2['email']."'");

  while( $query6 = mysql_fetch_array($query5) ) {           
    if ( $array_filter == $query6['atime'] ) {
      //it force "booked" as soon as 1 is booked
      $is_booked = true;

    } else {
     // OR uncomment here to force "available" as soon as 1 is availabe
     //$is_booked = false;

    }           
  }

  if ($is_booked) {
    echo $array_filter . '<br /><span style="color:red;background-color:#C0C0C0;">Booked</span>';
  } else {
    echo $array_filter . '<br /><span style="color:red;">Available</span>';
  }
?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Proger_Cbsk.

Comment: I don't understand how this gives you a list of all existing slots. But ok, if that is what you accept...